Indesign, text box that reflects file name every time I save?
My documents are updated regularly throughout the year, I place the date of last change and a name in a small text box on the bottom of the page to keep track of versions(once printed and in distribution). I want to make this an automatic feature of my documents so that every time I save my project, the date-label is updated with the current date.
The "file name" text variable suits my purposes best as it includes other critical identifying information. I was disappointed to find that simply inserting this into a text box just yields a static line of text, ie this text is not updated when the file name is changed. How can I make this dynamic?
I'm not a total stranger to scripting but I have no idea where to start, Thank you
Working in Windows 11, current version of Indesign

I found my own answer, In a text box I placed a piece of static information and then the text variable "output date":
"store 7 (output date)"
I copy and pasted this everywhere I needed and it suits my purposes. Before I would sometimes forget to manually update this information and incorrectly labeled documents entered distribution.
